# How to update git version correctly?

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I downloaded a new version of git - version 2.26.0 using command:

`brew upgrade git`
But i can't use it! If I type:

```
git --version
$ git version 2.22.0
```

If I try to update it again:

```
brew upgrade git
Warning: git 2.26.0 already installed
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: If `which git` doesn't return `/usr/local/bin/git` then you aren't using the Homebrew version.  You need to fix your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two versions of git, one provided by the operating system, one installed by brew.
There can be two issues:

1. The folder where `brew` puts executables is not in the `$PATH`.
2. The folder where `brew` puts executables is in `$PATH` but later than the folder where the OS-provided `git` is, so `git` from the other folder is executed.

By executing `which git` you'll see which `git` is being used.

There are multiple solutions: You may want to put brew folder at the beginning of `$PATH`, or install `brew` to a different folder. Check brew documentation for best practices.

Answer (score 14):

I used:

`brew link --overwrite git`

It has overwritten my current version of git to installed by brew - version 2.26.0.

Comment: After searching for hours , it worked using your command

Comment: This works in MacOS 12.4 Monterrey, same as @HelloUniverse I just needed to link the new version